# elementary school-like math operation

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, formatting, math-operators, mathtools

I'd like to write an equation formatted like this

[image]

Term can be writted with `siunitx` package, but to align them like this? `\flalign{}` doesn't do exactly what I ask.
Any idea?

Answer (score 6):

You may use `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{
  c % the operation symbol
  r % the numbers
  @{\,}% the separation
  l % the units
}
  &  1123 & \unit{\gram\per\hour} \\
+ &    10 & \unit{\gram\per\hour} \\
+ & 63112 & \unit{\gram\per\hour} \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
  & 64245 & \unit{\gram\per\hour}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You say: "Term can be written with siunitx package". It means: it can or may not. I didn't use this package and I did use plain TeX and `\halign` primitive:

```
\def\unit{g/h}
\halign{\llap{#}&\hfil#\cr
    &  1123 \unit\cr
  + &    10 \unit\cr
  + & 63112 \unit\cr \noalign{\smallskip\hrule\smallskip}
    & 64245 \unit\cr
}

\bye
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply used the `align*` environment. Use `&` to align at that point.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
& \SI{1123}{g/h} \\
+ & \SI{1123}{g/h} \\
+ & \SI{1123}{g/h} \\
\rule{45pt}{0.5pt}&\rule{45pt}{0.5pt}\\
= & \SI{1123}{g/h}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

You can change the thickness and length of the line. The command rule works like this: `\rule{length}{thickness}`. If you have numbers of different length, you may need to move the `&` to the end of the line (before `\\`).

Comment: A pair of braces should be added before the `+` sign, in order to have a correct spacing.